Вывод результатов поиска в блок
Когда я попадаю на страницу results.php в левом блоке выводятся результаты поиска. Рядом с этим блоком расположен календарь, а справа - блоки поиска. Нужно чтобы при клике на дату в календаре - очищался левый блок и блоки поиска, после этого выводить события с датой в левый блок.. Из всего что получилось... при клике на дату - очистка левого блока и поисковых блоков.
'''
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    $searchByName = isset($_GET['searchByName']) ? $_GET['searchByName'] : '';
    $searchDate = isset($_GET['searchDate']) ? $_GET['searchDate'] : '';
    $isAnniversary = isset($_GET['isAnniversary']) ? $_GET['isAnniversary'] : '';
    $sql = "SELECT events.*,
            (SELECT MAX(files.file_name)
            FROM event_files
            LEFT JOIN files ON event_files.file_id = files.file_id
            WHERE event_files.event_id = events.event_id) AS file_name
            FROM events
            WHERE 1";
    $params = [];
    $paramTypes = "";
    if (!empty($searchByName)) {
        $sql .= " AND (event_name LIKE ? OR event_description LIKE ? OR event_archive_cipher LIKE ?)";
        $paramTypes .= "sss";
        $searchParam = '%' . $searchByName . '%';
        $params[] = $searchParam;
        $params[] = $searchParam;
        $params[] = $searchParam;
    }
    if (!empty($searchDate)) {
        if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{4})$/', $searchDate, $matches)) {
            $startDate = $matches[1];
            $endDate = $matches[2];
        } elseif (preg_match('/^(\d{4})$/', $searchDate, $matches)) {
            $startDate = $matches[1];
            $endDate = $matches[1];
        } else {
            $startDate = null;
            $endDate = null;
        }
        if ($startDate !== null && $endDate !== null) {
            $sql .= " AND (
                        (LENGTH(events.event_date) = 4 AND
                        CAST(events.event_date AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR 
                        (LENGTH(events.event_date) = 10 AND
                        STR_TO_DATE(events.event_date, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                     )";
            $paramTypes .= "ssss";
            $params[] = $startDate;
            $params[] = $endDate;
            $params[] = $startDate . '-01-01';
            $params[] = $endDate . '-12-31';
        }
    }
    if ($isAnniversary) {
        $sql .= " AND ( LENGTH(events.event_date) = 4 OR
                       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(events.event_date, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m') = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('21.02.1959', '%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m'))";
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <form method="POST" class="search-form" action="search.php" id="searchForm" style="margin-top:100px">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left-side">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div style="color: black; font-weight: bold; padding: 20px;" id="searchResults">
                            <?php
                            function getYearsSinceEvent($eventDate)
                            {
                                // Если дата уже в формате "гггг"
                                if (strlen($eventDate) === 4) {
                                    $currentYear = date('Y');
                                    $yearsSinceEvent = $currentYear - intval($eventDate);
                                    return $yearsSinceEvent;
                                }
                                $eventDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $eventDate);
                                if ($eventDateTime !== false) {
                                    $currentDateTime = new DateTime();
                                    $interval = $currentDateTime->diff($eventDateTime);
                                    return $interval->y;
                                }
                                return "Ошибка в формате даты";
                            }
                            if (!empty($params)) {
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                                if ($stmt === false) {
                                    die('Error preparing the query: ' . $conn->error);
                                }
                                $stmt->bind_param($paramTypes, ...$params);
                                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                    $totalRecords = $result->num_rows;
                                    echo "<h2 class='text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'>Всего найдено событий: " . $totalRecords . "</h2><br>";
                                    if ($totalRecords > 0) {
                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo '<a class="event-link" href="event-card.php?event_id=' . $row["event_id"] . '" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; transition: color 0.3s ease;">';
                                            echo "<h4>&bull;Дата события: " . str_replace('!', '.', $row["event_date"]) . " (" . getYearsSinceEvent($row["event_date"]) . " лет)</h4>";
                                            echo "<h6><u>Название события</u>: " . $row["event_name"] . "</h6>";
                                            $description = $row["event_description"];
                                            $limitedDescription = (strlen($description) > 120) ? substr($description, 0, 120) . '...' : $description;
                                            echo "<h6 style='border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;'><u>Описание события</u>: " . $limitedDescription . "</h6>";
                                            echo '</a>';
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    die('Error executing the query: ' . $stmt->error);
                                }
                                $stmt->close();
                            }
                            $conn->close();
}
?>
                        <div class="event">
                            <h2></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                let currentDate = new Date();
                function updateCalendarView() {
                    const monthAndYear = currentDate.toString('MMMM yyyy');
                    document.getElementById('monthAndYear').textContent = monthAndYear;
                }
                function previous() {
                    currentDate = currentDate.add(-1).month();
                    updateCalendarView();
                }
                function next() {
                    currentDate = currentDate.add(1).month();
                    updateCalendarView();
                }
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    updateCalendarView();
                    document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        event.preventDefault();
                        previous();
                    });
                    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        event.preventDefault();
                        next();
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="container-calendar">
                    <div id="">
                        <div class="header-container-calendar">
                            <div class="button-container-calendar">
                                <button type="button" id="previous" onclick="previous()">
                                    ‹
                                </button>
                                <h3 id="monthAndYear"></h3>
                                <button type="button" id="next" onclick="next()">
                                    ›
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table-calendar" id="calendar" data-lang="ru">
                            <thead id="thead-month"></thead>
                            <!-- Table body for displaying the calendar -->
                            <tbody id="calendar-body"></tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="footer-container-calendar text-center">
                            <label for="month"></label>
                            <select id="month" onchange="jump()">
                                <option value=0>Январь</option>
                                <option value=1>Февраль</option>
                                <option value=2>Март</option>
                                <option value=3>Апрель</option>
                                <option value=4>Май</option>
                                <option value=5>Июнь</option>
                                <option value=6>Июль</option>
                                <option value=7>Август</option>
                                <option value=8>Сентябрь</option>
                                <option value=9>Октябрь</option>
                                <option value=10>Ноябрь</option>
                                <option value=11>Декабрь</option>
                            </select>
                            <!-- Dropdown to select a specific year -->
                            <select id="year" onchange="jump()"></select>
                            <span>год</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./resscript.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="search-container" style="background-color:white; ">
                    <div class="bordered-container">
                        <label for="searchByName">Поиск по ключевым словам</label>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <input type="text" name="searchByName" id="searchByName"
                                value="<?php echo isset($searchByName) ? $searchByName : ''; ?>"
                                onblur="validateInput()" class="text-center">
                            <span class="tooltip-text">Введите ключевые слова для поиска. Можно использовать
                                одно или несколько слов.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search-container" style="background-color:white;">
                    <div class="bordered-container">
                        <label for="searchDate">Поиск по дате</label>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <input type="text" pattern="\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{4}" id="searchDate"
                                value="<?php echo isset($searchDate) ? $searchDate : ''; ?>" name="searchDate"
                                class="text-center">
                            <span class="tooltip-text">Поддерживается поиск по периоду и по году <br> (например,
                                1916-1920 или 1916).</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="error-message" id="searchDateError"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search-container" style="background-color:white;text-align: center;" id="checkboxDiv">
                    <div class="bordered-container">
                        <label for="isAnniversary" class="checkbox-label">Юбилейная дата?</label>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="isAnniversary" class="demoToggleCheckbox" name="isAnniversary"
                                <?php echo $isAnniversary ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
                            <label for="isAnniversary" class="checkbox-toggle"></label>
                            <span class="tooltip-text">Отметьте, если ищете юбилейные даты.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="reminder-list"></div>
                <div class="button-row">
                    <div>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <button type="submit" class="search" style="font-size: large;">
                                <img src="play-button_1710004.png" width="64" height="64">
                            </button>
                            <span class="tooltip-text">Поиск</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tooltip-container">
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" id="clear-button" class="clear" style="font-size: large;margin-left: 10px;">
                                <img src="cross-red.webp" width="64" height="64">
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip-text">Очистить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                sendAjaxRequest(formData);
            });
            document.querySelector('.search-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var searchByName = document.getElementById('searchByName').value;
                var searchDate = document.getElementById('searchDate').value;
                var isAnniversary = document.getElementById('isAnniversary').checked;
                searchResults(searchByName, searchDate, isAnniversary);
            });
            document.getElementById('clear-button').addEventListener('click', clearFormAndResults);
            function searchResults(searchByName, searchDate, isAnniversary) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "search.php", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send("searchByName=" + searchByName + "&searchDate=" + searchDate + "&isAnniversary=" +
                    isAnniversary);
            }
            function clearFormAndResults(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                clearForm();
                clearSearchResults();
                clearURLParameters();
            }
            function clearForm() {
                $("#searchForm")[0].reset();
                $("#searchByName").val('');
                $("#searchDate").val('');
                document.getElementById('isAnniversary').checked = false;
            }
            $("#clearButton").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                clearFormAndResults();
                clearCheckbox();
            });
            function clearSearchResults() {
                $("#searchResults").empty();
            }
            function clearURLParameters() {
                var newUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
                window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

'''
resscript.js

    let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
    let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body");
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let today = new Date();
        let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
        let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
        let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
        let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");
        let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
        let reminderList = document.getElementById("reminder-list");
        let events = [];
        let months = [
            "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
            "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"
        ];
        let days = ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"];
        let dataHead = "<tr>";
        for (let day of days) {
            dataHead += `<th data-days='${day}'>${day}</th>`;
        }
        dataHead += "</tr>";
        document.getElementById("thead-month").innerHTML = dataHead;
        function generateYearRange(start, end) {
            let years = "";
            for (let year = start; year <= end; year++) {
                years += `<option value='${year}'>${year}</option>`;
            }
            return years;
        }
        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
        }
        function clearForm() {
            document.getElementById('searchByName').value = '';
            document.getElementById('searchDate').value = '';
            document.getElementById('isAnniversary').checked = false;
        }
        function clearSearchResults() {
            document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = '';
        }
        function getEventsOnDate(date, month, year) {
            return events.filter(event => {
                let eventDate = convertDateStringToDateObject(event.date);
                return (
                    eventDate.getDate() === date &&
                    eventDate.getMonth() === month &&
                    eventDate.getFullYear() === year
                );
            });
        }
    
        function hasEventOnDate(date, month, year) {
            return getEventsOnDate(date, month, year).length > 0;
        }
    
        function createEventTooltip(date, month, year) {
            let tooltip = document.createElement("div");
            tooltip.className = "event-tooltip";
            let eventsOnDate = getEventsOnDate(date, month, year);
            for (let event of eventsOnDate) {
                let eventDate = convertDateStringToDateObject(event.date);
                let eventText = `<strong>${event.title}</strong> - ${event.description} on ${eventDate.toLocaleDateString()}`;
                let eventElement = document.createElement("p");
                eventElement.innerHTML = eventText;
                tooltip.appendChild(eventElement);
            }
            return tooltip;
        }
        function convertDateStringToDateObject(dateString) {
            const parts = dateString.split(".");
            const day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            const month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1;
            const year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
            return new Date(year, month, day);
        }
        function clearFormAndResults(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            clearForm();
            clearSearchResults();
            clearURLParameters();
            document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = '';
        }
        function showCalendar(month = today.getMonth(), year = today.getFullYear(), clearSearch = false) {
            if (clearSearch) {
                clearForm();
                clearSearchResults();
                let eventDiv = document.querySelector('.event');
                if (!eventDiv) {
                    eventDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    eventDiv.classList.add('event');
                    document.body.appendChild(eventDiv); // или добавьте его в нужное место в вашем HTML-коде
                }
                eventDiv.innerHTML = ''; // очищаем блок с событиями
            }
            let firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
            let daysToSkip = (firstDay + 6) % 7; // This will ensure that the calendar starts from Monday
    
            let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body");
            tbl.innerHTML = "";
            monthAndYear.innerHTML = `${months[month]} ${year}`;
            selectYear.value = year;
            selectMonth.value = month;
    
            let date = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                let row = document.createElement("tr");
                for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    if (i === 0 && j < daysToSkip) {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                        cell.appendChild(cellText);
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    } else if (date > daysInMonth(month, year)) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        cell.setAttribute("data-date", date);
                        cell.setAttribute("data-month", month + 1);
                        cell.setAttribute("data-year", year);
                        cell.setAttribute("data-month_name", months[month]);
                        cell.addEventListener('click', function () {
                            let clickedDate = this.getAttribute("data-date");
                            let clickedMonth = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-month"));
                            let clickedYear = this.getAttribute("data-year");
                            clearForm();
                            clearSearchResults();
                            let eventDiv = document.querySelector('.event');
                            if (eventDiv) {
                                eventDiv.innerHTML = '';
                            }
                            let previouslySelected = document.querySelector('.selected');
                            if (previouslySelected) {
                                previouslySelected.classList.remove('selected');
                            }
                            this.classList.add('selected');
                            let url = `get_events_by_date.php?date=${clickedDate}&month=${clickedMonth}&year=${clickedYear}`;
                            let monthNames = ['Января', 'Февраля', 'Марта', 'Апреля', 'Мая', 'Июня', 'Июля', 'Августа', 'Сентября', 'Октября', 'Ноября', 'Декабря'];
                            fetch(url)
                                .then(response => response.json())
                                .then(data => {
                                    let eventDiv = document.querySelector('.event');
                                    if (eventDiv) {
                                        eventDiv.innerHTML = "";
                                        if (data.length > 0) {
                                            let monthName = monthNames[clickedMonth - 1];
                                            eventDiv.innerHTML += `<h2>События ${clickedDate} ${monthName}</h2>`;
                                            data.forEach(event => {
                                                let eventDate = event.event_date.split(".");
                                                let eventMonthName = monthNames[eventDate - 1];
                                                let eventText = `<div class="event-details tooltip-container" style="text-align: left;">
                                                <a style="font-size: 20px" class="event-link" href='http://192.168.0.100/event-card.php?event_id=${event.event_id}'>
                                                &bull;
                                                ${eventDate} ${eventMonthName} ${eventDate} - ${event.event_name}: ${event.event_description}
                                                </a>
                                                <span class="tooltip-text">Нажмите, чтобы ознакомиться подробнее</span>
                                                </div>`;
                                                eventDiv.innerHTML += eventText;
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            let clickedMonthIndex = clickedMonth - 1;
                                            let formattedDate = `${clickedDate} ${monthNames[clickedMonthIndex]} ${clickedYear}`;
                                            eventDiv.innerHTML += `<h4 style="text-align: center; color: red; margin-top:45%">На ${formattedDate.slice(0, -5)} события отсутствуют </h4>`;
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching events:', error));
                        });
    
                        cell.className = "date-picker";
                        cell.innerHTML = "<span>" + date + "</span>";
                        if (
                            date === today.getDate() &&
                            year === today.getFullYear() &&
                            month === today.getMonth()
                        ) {
                            cell.className = "date-picker selected";
                        }
                        if (hasEventOnDate(date, month, year)) {
                            cell.classList.add("event-marker");
                            cell.appendChild(createEventTooltip(date, month, year));
                        }
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                        date++;
                    }
                }
                tbl.appendChild(row);
            }
            displayReminders();
        }
        let years = generateYearRange(1970, 2050);
        document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = years;
        document.getElementById("next").addEventListener('click', next);
        document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener('click', previous);
        selectYear.addEventListener('change', jump);
        selectMonth.addEventListener('change', jump);
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        function next() {
            currentYear = currentMonth === 11 ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
            currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
            showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    });


get_events_by_date.php

    <?php
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    $formattedDate = sprintf('%02d.%02d.%04d', $date, $month, $year);
    $sql = "SELECT event_id, event_name, event_description, event_date FROM events WHERE DAY(STR_TO_DATE(event_date, '%d.%m.%Y')) = '$date' AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(event_date, '%d.%m.%Y')) = '$month'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
    }
    $events = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $events[] = $row;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($events);
    ?>


